# Mongoose: how to add dynamic index to a schema?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a long collection of employees stored in a mongodb database. Their properties are defined in a mongoose schema called EmployeesSchema. In order to speed up queries, I would like to implement indexes depending on their jobs, so mongo only has to check employees that belong to a specific job.

How can I dynamically create such an index?

```js
var EmployeesSchema = new Schema({
    name: "joe"
    job: "manager"
}

schema.createIndex({"job": "manager"});
```

Also, how should I write my mongoose query in order to take advantage of this index? Would EmployeesSchema.find({name: "joe“}).job(“manager“) work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax to create an index on the job field is like this:

```js
schema.createIndex({"job": 1});
```

Now to be able to find employees based on the `job`, you need to query like this:

```js
EmployeesModel.find({job: "manager"});
```

Comment: Thanks! However, Mongoose's doc says I can define an index directly in the schema. Also, what does "1" stands for here? Does it mean "create an index called job, and add all employees in it? If so, what would be the difference with a basic query find({job: "manager"})?

Comment: @DoneDeal0 1 shows tthe direction in the index, more info at the official [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes) or [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/)

Comment: @DoneDeal0 so did you make it work? If so please consider marking this as answer.